# Entity Framework stored procedure returns null object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have an ASP.NET MVC site and I want to display some details from a stored procedure. I have done the exact same thing before with other stored procedures on different pages in the same app and it has worked, but this stored procedure call returns a null object instead of the expected value.

EF call to stored procedure:

```
public MostRecentOrderDetail GetMostRecentOrder(int userId)
{
    var context = new myDatabaseContext();
    var paramUserId = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "viUserId", Value = userId };
    var result = context.Database.SqlQuery<MostRecentOrderDetail>("usp#GetMostRecentOrder @viUserId", paramUserId).FirstOrDefault();
    return result;
}
```

In my controller I call it using:

```
MostRecentOrderDetail latestOrder = myDB.GetMostRecentOrder(CurrentUser.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
```

When I call the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio it returns a single row table populated with the correct values, I just cannot seem to get my ASP.NET MVC site to see it.

The MVC site uses code-first, and the `MostRecentOrderDetail` object is correctly mapped to the columns of the stored procedure.

*EDIT

I have updated my code as @DanielDrews suggested below, and am now receiving an exception, which I think is a step forward:

```
The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'MyApp.Models.MostRecentOrderDetail'. A member of the type, 'OrderTypeCode', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
```

I believe my model is being mapped correctly.

myDatabaseContext.cs

```
public partial class myDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    // Database Initializer etc

    public IDbSet<MostRecentOrderDetail> MostRecentOrderDetails { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // ... Other Maps
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MostRecentOrderMap());
    }
    // GetMostRecentOrder() function from above
}
```

MostRecentOrderMap.cs

```
 public class MostRecentOrderMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<MostRecentOrderDetail>
    {
        public MostRecentOrderMap()
            {    
                // Table and Column Mappings
                this.ToTable("usp#GetMostRecentOrder");

                this.Property(t => t.OrderTypeCode).HasColumnName("order_type_code");
                this.Property(t => t.OrderStatusCode).HasColumnName("order_status_code");
                this.Property(t => t.OrderReceivedDate).HasColumnName("order_received_date");
                this.Property(t => t.OrderShippedDate).HasColumnName("order_shipped_date");    
            }

    }
```

MostRecentOrderDetail.cs

```
public class MostRecentOrderDetail
{
    [Key]
    public string OrderTypeCode { get; set; }
    public string OrderStatusCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderReceivedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderShippedDate { get; set; }
}
```

The stored procedure itself:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp#GetMostRecentOrder]
         @viUserId int
AS
begin
SELECT TOP 1    o.order_type_code, 
        o.order_status_code,
        o.order_received_date, 
        o.order_shipped_date 
FROM    ORDER_TABLE o 
WHERE   o.user_id = @viUserId
end
```

Comment: `UserId` is definitely being passed properly?

Comment: @Papa Yes, as far as I can tell it is passing it, A breakpoint on the `return` line shows `UserID` has `Base: @viUserId , DBType: Int32, Value: 1234` (my test user id). I cant seem to inspect the actual query being executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a problem with the parameter viUserId (value is correct?), try to initialize like this:

```
var paramUserId = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "viUserId", Value = userId };
```

in my applications i've call procedures a little bit diferent. Translating to your problems should be like that:

```
var paramUserId = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "viUserId", Value = userId };
var result = this.DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<MostRecentOrderDetail>("usp#GetMostRecentOrder @viUserId", paramUserId).FirstOrDefault();
```

And one last thing. be sure they have the same types (mapping and database). this could lead to an exception

*EDIT

The procedure need to return all properties from your model (the same name). procedure returns 'order_type_code' but model expects OrderTypeCode.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my code to use what you suggested, I do now get an exception, but not because of the `viUserId` parameter, I have updated the original question with more detail.

Comment: Jake, the procedure need to return all properties from your model (the same name). procedure returns 'order_type_code' but expects OrderTypeCode.
"[...]does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name."

Comment: This was it! even with the mapping file, I needed to change my model property names to match the database column names exactly. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your parameter code. Your missing `@` in `"viUserId"`

```
UserID = new SqlParameter("@viUserId", userId);
```

Comment: I updated the code to include the `@` but it is still returning a null object.